# Autenticação de usuário com $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em que dependendo do nível do usuário ele é redirecionado para uma página

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $http, config) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if ($location.path() != "/Login") {

      $http.get(config.BaseUrl + "/auth.php").success(function(inf) {
        if (typeof inf == "object") {
          if (inf.nivel > 0) {
            $location.path("/ContratosCorretor") ;
          }
```

Ou seja, se o nível do usuário for maior que 0, ele é corretor e será redirecionado para a página dele, porém ele vai poder acessar mais uma página

```
  $routeProvider.when("/NovoContratoCorretor", {
    templateUrl: "view/NovoContratoCorretor.html",
    controller: "NovoContratoCorretor",
  })
```

e dessa forma que está meu $rootscope e sempre sera redicerionado para  para `/ContratosCorretor`.. Alguém tem alguma solução pra esse problema?

Comment: Se entendi bem o que quer fazer, dependendo do nível de acesso o usuário é redirecionado para uma página é isso?

Comment: Isso, Dependendo do nivel dele, ele é redirecionado pra uma página, mas ele só consegue acessar aquela página... eu quero que ele possa acessar mais uma

Comment: O usuário só fica preso aquela página, mas eu quero que ele possa navegar por mais uma

Comment: Nesse caso, entendo que quando o usuário acessar a primeira vez será redirecionado para uma página default. Após ele poderá navegar entre páginas através de um menu acredito. É isso? Se sim o que você precisa é um menu dinâmico que seja compilado em tempo de execução conforme o nível do usuário. Certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você determine uma variável de nível antes de configurar as rotas dessa forma:

```
if (nivel == 1) {
    angularApp.config(
                ['$routeProvider',
                    function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                 .when("/NovoContratoCorretor", {
                        templateUrl: "view/NovoContratoCorretor.html",
                        controller: "NovoContratoCorretor",
                 })
                 .when("/OutraPagina", {
                        templateUrl: "view/OutraTemplate.html",
                        controller: "OutraController",
                 })

               ]);
               }
}
```

Ou se você preferir, você pode estabelecer um nível para cada rota, e fazer a verificação do nível no controller:

```
     $routeProvider
                .when("/NovoContratoCorretor", {
                     templateUrl: "view/NovoContratoCorretor.html",
                     controller: "NovoContratoCorretor",
                     niveis: [1,2]
                     })
                .when("/OutraPagina", {
                     templateUrl: "view/OutraTemplate.html",
                     controller: "OutraController",
                     niveis: [2,3]
                });
```

No controle você captura o nível:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $http, config, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if ($location.path() != "/Login") {

      $http.get(config.BaseUrl + "/auth.php").success(function(inf) {
        if (typeof inf == "object") {
          if (angular.isDefined($routeParams.niveis[inf.nivel])) {
               $location.path("/ContratosCorretor") ;
          }
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que analisar em toda rota uma regra que só é válida após o login, é um desperdício de processamento.
Você pode registrar um listener específico para a variável de usuário e só redirecionar o mesmo quando ela mudar, da seguinte maneira:

```
$rootScope.$watch('nomeDaVariavelDeUsuario', function(novoUsuario) {
  if(novoUsuario.nivel > 0) {
    $location.path("/ContratosCorretor");
  }
});
```

Desta maneira, você só vai efetuar redirecionamento para página inicial quando o objeto for efetivamente alterado, seja por login ou algo do tipo. Em todas as outras rotas de navegação, vai funcionar corretamente.

Apenas como complemento, o seu código não funcionou pois você deu um binding no evento de troca de rota, então sempre que a rota era diferente da de login, você automaticamente redirecionava o usuário para a sua página inicial.